# How to send mail from exchange server without smtp?

Tags: c#-4.0, smtp

I am currently sending mails from my code using smtp, but seems like we will have to migrate to exchange server, is there a difference between the two?
What changes I need to do in my code?

```
MailMessage loginInfo = new MailMessage();
loginInfo.To.Add("estinationaddress.@ca");
loginInfo.From = new MailAddress("abc@sde.ca");
loginInfo.Subject = "ABC";
loginInfo.Body = "Your username is: " +"abc";
loginInfo.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "www.smtphost.com";
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@sde.ca","abc");
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(loginInfo);
```

What changes I will be needing in my code?

Comment: Exchange is an SMTP server

Comment: @Barmar: This is a requirement by my client, they are asking me to use exchange servers now, so I am quite confused. :(

Comment: SMTP is a protocol, Exchange is a software application that implements that protocol.